# which programming language has a large library that can do machine learning algorithm, R, matlab or python

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, data-mining, python, r

As what I described in the title, we are especially interested in those for dealing with big data----ts efficiency and stability, and used in industry not in experiment or university. Thanks!

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is usually considered off topic for StackExchange. I think it could be a better question if you could narrow down requirements and ask for how to accomplish this in the few tools you are considering using.

Comment: The answer to your question is "all of them". Depending on where the real detailed challenges to your problem are, one language might give you better support for what you want to do. But to answer that, the question needs a *lot* more detail.

Comment: I think you need to decide how good is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

I've making some researches last months and I could find more libraries, contente and active community with Python. Actually I'm using it to ETL processes, some minning jobs and to make map/reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Scala is the only real language that has Big Data at it's core. You have MLLib that sits on Spark, and as Scala is Functional it makes parallel computing really natural.  R, Python and Matlab are not suitable for industry productization, well some would say Python's horrible dynamic typing can be handled a little using special build tools, but really its not type safe and there is no way to solve that problem.